какое это придаточное?
"...Левитан работал с таким рвением, словно боялся, что в этом милом краю..."
Не могу определиться — это придаточное определительное, сравнения, образа действия? Помогите, пожалуйста

...Левитан работал с таким рвением, словно боялся, что в этом милом краю...
Пояснение

Боялся (чего?),  что в этом милом краю...

Это придаточное изъяснительное, союз ЧТО, опорное слово бояться со значением эмоциональной реакции.

Также здесь однородные сказуемые работал, словно боялся.  В этом случае сравнительный союз словно дифференцирует значение сказуемого.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Ну можно так разобрать:
...Левитан работал с таким рвением, словно (он) боялся, что в этом милом краю...
Три предикативные основы, последовательное подчинение двух придаточных.
Первое придаточное со значением определение + сравнение, местоименно-союзная связь, указательное слово ТАКИМ, опорное существительное РВЕНИЕМ, союз  БУДТО: с таким рвением, будто...
Второе придаточное:  Боялся (чего?),  что в этом милом краю...
Придаточное изъяснительное, союз ЧТО, опорное слово бояться со значением эмоциональной реакции.

Меня интересует именно "словно боялся". это же тоже придаточное маленькое. про "боялся" — понятно
